# Manipulate updates due to variable changes outside manipulate: can this be stopped?

Tags: manipulate

I have created a large notebook where i have two or more manipulates whose execution is supposed to wait till I click an update button. The button operates a dummy update variable which is tracked in the various manipulates as shown in the hypothetical situation below

```
Manipulate[update; a, {a,0,1}, TrackedSymbols :> {a, update}]
Manipulate[update; b, {b,0,1}, TrackedSymbols :> {b, update}]
update = 0; Button["update", update = 1 - update]
```

However, my functions in my manipulates have use a variable from outside the manipulate called "Pii2, tF2, and h2 ".  These and other variables are controls inside an independent grid as shown in the second code snippet below.  When I change Pii2, tF2, or h2 in the grids, both my manipulate functions described above update.

My questions: how do I keep the manipulates from updating when Pii2, tF2, or h2 are changed.  I only want the manipulates to update to just the tracked variables.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
Grid[{
  {Dynamic[
    InputField[   
     Dynamic[ Pii2, Initialization -> (Pii2 = SerializedData[[1]])], 
     Number, FieldHint -> "Initial Pressure", FieldSize -> Tiny]]},
  {Dynamic[
    InputField[   
     Dynamic[tF2, Initialization -> (tF2 = SerializedData[[4]])], 
     Number, FieldHint -> "Formation Temperature", 
     FieldSize -> Tiny]]},
  {Dynamic[
    InputField[   
     Dynamic[h2, Initialization -> (  h2 = SerializedData[[7]]  )], 
     Number, FieldHint -> "Net Pay", FieldSize -> Tiny]]}
  }, Alignment -> {Right, Center}]
```

Comment: You would need to localize the variables in the manipulate that you didn't want to change until the `Module` was evaluated. For example: `x = 12;
Module[{x = x},
 Manipulate[
  ToString[x] <> ", " <> ToString[y]
  , {y, 0, 1}]
 ]`

Comment: So should the Manipulate update when you drag the `a` slider or not? I think this question needs a minimal working example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @flinty thanks for the feedback, I will give it a shoot.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, The manipulate does update when sliders or normal manipulate controls are changed.  However, the function inside the manipulate uses a variable that is defined elsewhere outside the manipulate.  For example,  the function Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}]  might uses the variable "b" which is provided by the user via an InputField[] in a grid outside the manipulate. The manipulate updates when a slider variable "a" is changed, or when a tracked symbol changes but unfortunately also when b is changed.

Comment: When I try a simple model (see img), it does not update when the global variable `foo` is changed, either by manual execution or through an `InputField`; it does update if I move the slider or click the update button: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ5Ub.png

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks I will take a look at your screen shot, and see what i have done differently.  Thanks for the feedback.  Colin